# Unable to select device on an existing Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

I made an Android project using Android Studio last year targeting the Kitkat version.

Today, I opened up the window again with the intent to update the app [since the API I was using has updated]. However, when I open the project, I do not have the `Android` toolbar.

This is a recent app I made that contains this toolbar where I can select the device to load the app to:

[image]

In the old project [the app I want to update], I am unable to find said "Android" toolbar. Neither am I able to load the app to my device, since it does not have this selection:

[image]

I am not entirely sure if it's the result of the way I opened the app. I just did:

```
File -> Open -> ThisAppOfMine
```

This is the sidebar:

[image]

I am on Android Studio 1.2.2

Comment: Which version of AS are you on?

Comment: I am on AS 1.2.2 the newest one

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing gradle files for the project you are importing.